# Search googleplaces localities by radius iOS from a CLLocationCoordinate

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to search the localities in the `GMSCircle` radius, I have a **reverseGeocodeFunction** which print all of the possible localities results from a `CllLocationCoordinate2D`:
`

```
func reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
  // 1
  let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()
  // 2
  geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate) { response, error in
   for address in response.results() {
     print ("\(address.locality)")
    }
   }
}`
```

Do you know how can I pass the radius coordinates to the function to obtain all the possible localities or how can I get all the near localities from a coordinate